# invariant violation: element type is invalid React native

Tags: react-native, export, render

I'm trying to import a component into my App.js class but when I try I get the error in my android emulator

```
invariant violation element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined you likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

check the render method of 'login'
```

my problem is that I checked that i'm importing a default import of the login component in my App.js and I am exporting the Login component correctly from what I can tell:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,ScrollView,View,Text,Input,Button,SecureTextEntry,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

 export default class Login extends Component {
     state={
         email: '',
         password: '',
         authenticating: false
     };

  componentDidMount(){
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'garbagekey',
    authDomain: 'garbage auth domain'
      }
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    }

    onButtonPress = () =>{
        console.log("button pressed")
        this.setState({authenticating:true})
    }

    contentBoolRender = () =>{
        if(this.state.authenticating===true){
            return(
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>

            </View>
            ) 
        }

        return(
            <View>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Enter your Email..."
                    label = "Email"
                    onChangeText = {email => this.setState({email})}
                    value = {this.state.email}
                />

                <Input
                    placeholder="Enter your Password..."
                    label = "Password"
                    onChangeText = {password => this.setState({password})}
                    value = {this.state.password}
                    SecureTextEntry
                />
                    <Button title="login" onpress={()=>this.onButtonPress()}></Button>
            </View>
        )
    }


  render() {
    return(
        <View>
        {this.contentBoolRender()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  login:{
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
});
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Notes from "./notes.js";
import CreateNote from "./createnote.js";
import Login from "./login.js";

 class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedin: false,
    notes: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "mow the lawn",
        author: "dean",
        time: "10am"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "feed the dog",
        author: "sam",
        time: "2pm"
      }
    ]
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyABmRXh2nlBt4FtjfOWNaoz7q5Wy5pGFlc',
    authDomain: 'familytodo-28018.firebaseapp.com'
      }
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    }
    confirmLogin=()=>{
      this.setState({loggedin:true})
    }


  updateNotes = (title, name, eventTime) => {
    console.log("making new note");
    let newNote = {
      text: title,
      author: name,
      time: eventTime
    };
    this.setState(state => {
      const list = state.notes.concat(newNote);
      console.log(list);
      return {
        notes: list
      };
    });
  };

  deleteNotes = note => {
    console.log("note deleted", note.id);

    this.setState(state => {
      var list = this.state.notes;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.notes.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.notes[i].id === note.id) {
          list.pop(i);
        }
      }
      return {
        notes: list
      };
    });
  };


  conditionalRender=()=>{
    if(this.state.loggedin===false){
      return (
        <View>
          <Login confirmlogin = {this.confirmLogin} />
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View>
          <CreateNote
            handleName={this.handleName}
            handleEvent={this.handleEvent}
            handleTime={this.handleTime}
            updateNotes={this.updateNotes}
          />
          <Notes style={styles.notes} notes={this.state.notes} deleteNotes={this.deleteNotes} />
        </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
   return(
    <View>
    {this.conditionalRender()}
    </View>
   );

  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    maxWidth: 500
  },
  logo: {
    height: 80
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 15,
    marginVertical: 10,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  notes:{
    marginHorizontal: '50%'
  },
  text: {
    lineHeight: 15,
    fontSize: 11,
    marginVertical: 11,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  link: {
    color: "#1B95E0"
  },
  code: {
    fontFamily: "monospace, monospace"
  }
});

export default App;
```

any help would be appreciate greatly please help me provide better info if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because `react-native` has no exported member named `Input`. I think you are looking for either `TextInput` (from `react-native`) or `Input` (from `react-native-elements` which has a `label` prop)

For the `TextInput`, try changing the login component to this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Button, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        authenticating: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 'garbagekey',
            authDomain: 'garbage auth domain'
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        console.log("button pressed");
        this.setState({authenticating: true});
    };

    contentBoolRender = () => {
        if (this.state.authenticating === true) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>

                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter your Email..."
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
                    value={this.state.email}
                />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter your Password..."
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    secureTextEntry
                />
                <Button title="login" onPress={() => this.onButtonPress()}/>
            </View>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.contentBoolRender()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

or for `Input` try using this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Button, View} from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        authenticating: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 'garbagekey',
            authDomain: 'garbage auth domain'
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        console.log("button pressed");
        this.setState({authenticating: true});
    };

    contentBoolRender = () => {
        if (this.state.authenticating === true) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>

                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Enter your Email..."
                    label = "Email"
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
                    value={this.state.email}
                />

                <Input
                    placeholder="Enter your Password..."
                    label = "Password"
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    secureTextEntry
                />
                <Button title="login" onPress={() => this.onButtonPress()}/>
            </View>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.contentBoolRender()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Additionally, have a look through the code above as your Login component had a few other typos including: secureTextEntry and onPress

Comment: thanks for the tip i'll try this out and provide an update!

Comment: Hey this worked out perfectly thanks for pointing the different inputs out, I’m brand new to react native :)